# Add medium like annotation features to a website

Tags: javascript, annotations

I have a website which displays some text. Right now, I want to build some features on top of that:

- highlight some portion of text of his choice
- add notes to   some portion of text of his choice

Then access these highlights and notes later just like what you can see on medium website.

See example  in the GIF in this link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EWn9ymHgxED3TyDUVhKkQTYTCdi3MPUY/view?usp=sharing

You can also visit medium website to get a better grasp of it:
https://medium.com/s/story/a-culture-of-prestige-98c8671ceade

I did some research and :

1 - I saw this tool:  http://annotatorjs.org/

2- I saw this experiment made: https://www.surfly.com/labs/extend-any-website-with-annotation-functionality# . The experiment got results close to what I want

Maybe it can help you or give you ideas.

MY QUESTIONS:

1- Do you know a plugin ( or another ready to use solution) that can help me achieve that goal ?

2- If you were in my situation, what would be your approach ?

Yours